# Convert iMac internal LCD panel to external monitor?

Tags: conversion, lcd, adapter, external-display, imac

My iMac died (power supply issue, out of warranty), so I took it apart to get at the HDD to recover some files.  In the process, I managed to remove the LCD panel.

My question is: is it possible/does there exist an adapter that I can use to convert this panel (with an internal connector) into an external monitor that accepts a DVI input?

Comment: Interesting question. I'd say if you have to ask, then no. You'd have to make or find prefabricated needed converters and such things are a bit complicated.

Comment: There are converter cards for this sort of thing but it's a huge pain and probably not worth your trouble.  (Probably something like http://www.orbitmicro.com/global/lvds-vga-r10-p-10904.html?ref=base)

Comment: What would make it a huge pain?  I mean, I know that its not something that people do every day, but it seems to me like I could just buy the converter card Shinrai suggested and plug it in.  I guess I would still need to find some way to get power to the panel.

Comment: I have a dead white MacBook, so this question is interesting to me too. Are the displays of iMac and MacBook comparable in the way they are connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **no**. The long one, probably yes, but you need extensive electrical knowledge. Here is a tutorial, but it's in french: http://users.skynet.be/fa835376/pas%20a%20pas.pdf