# Converting laptop's internal LCD to external display

Tags: laptop, macbook, display, mini-displayport

I have two 17" Macbook Pro's. One is dead, other one is alive.

I disassembled the dead one, and removed it's working display successfully.

As I see it, it has a LG LP171WU6-TLA1 display with 40 pins connector. And it needs power (I'm guessing, 12V 3,3)

My question is,

1) how do I make an adapter mini-dvi to that 40 pins connector? Is there one on sale?
2) can I power it using my USB ports? If yes, how? if no, how else I can power it up?

Thanks!

Comment: it'll be cool if you figure it out...good luck

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://superuser.com/questions/175565/convert-imac-internal-lcd-panel-to-external-monitor) question. It's extremely similar.